# Why doesn't Flash kill OR knock out OR tie up faster (in seconds)?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

Really, **why Flash doesn't** kill **OR** knock out **OR** tie up **Bad Guys in seconds?**

- He can do it.
- He has A LOT of time.
- He can literally do anything with those poor bad guys.

*This question not about supernatural abilities of Flash and Bad Guys.* Yes, some of them are protected of being knocked out in a second. But others are not protected and cant react so quickly. They can do some damage only if Flash gives them time, and he gives it.

.

**Why so long and complicated?**.

.

Note: Here, The Flash = a superhero. This question is based only on TV show, but I think there is the same issue in comics.

Comment: If the flash went around killing his enemies, he wouldn't be much of a hero. More of an armed vigilante. The only person in scifi that I can think of that does that sort of thing is Rorschach

Comment: It's a cheesy TV show based on a rather cheesy super hero. Don't overthink it and just enjoy the badly written show :D

Comment: In the episode Rogue Time Flash laid a super speedy smackdown on Mark Mardon (not to death, but enough so he could be brought to and contained within the pipeline) so I would argue that as an example where he *did* knock out or tie up a baddie in seconds.